# R creating new column without for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

Suppose I have a data frame with a few numbers in the first column. I want to take these numbers, use them as locations in a string, and take a substring that includes 2 characters before and after that location. To clarify,

```
aggSN <- data.frame(V1=c(5,6,7,8),V2="blah")
gen <- "AJSDAFKSDAFJKLASDFKJKA"  # <- take this string
aggSN                            # <- take the numbers in the first column
# V1    V2
#  5  blah
#  6  blah
#  7  blah
#  8  blah
```

and create a new column V3 that looks like

```
aggSN                           
# V1    V2    V3
#  5  blah SDAFK   # <- took the two characters before and after the 5th character
#  6  blah DAFKS   # <- took the two characters before and after the 6th character 
#  7  blah AFKSD   # <- took the two characters before and after the 7th character 
# 10  blah SDAFJ   # <- took the two characters before and after the 10th character 
#  2  blah AJSD   # <- here you can see that it the substring cuts off
```

Currently I am using a for loop, which works, but takes a lot of time on very large data frames and large strings. Are there any alternatives to this? Thank you.

```
fillvector <- ""
for(j in 1:nrow(aggSN)){fillvector[j] <- substr(gen,aggSN[j,V1]-2,aggSN[j,V1]+2)}
aggSN$V9 <- fillvector
```

Comment: What happens if boundaries are out of range 1 .. length(gen)?

Comment: I will edit my post shortly after this comment, but I would want the substring to just cut off.

Comment: It should be `aggSN[j, V1]`, shouldn't it?

Comment: From where comes your "10" in aggSN, after creating V3?

Comment: Sorry,you're right, I changed it to `aggSN[j,V1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `substring()` without writing a loop

```
aggSN <- data.frame(V1=c(5,6,7,8,2),V2="blah")
gen <- "AJSDAFKSDAFJKLASDFKJKA" 

with(aggSN, substring(gen, V1-2, V1+2))
# [1] "SDAFK" "DAFKS" "AFKSD" "FKSDA" "AJSD"
```

So to add the new column,

```
aggSN$V3 <- with(aggSN, substring(gen, V1-2, V1+2))
aggSN
#   V1   V2    V3
# 1  5 blah SDAFK
# 2  6 blah DAFKS
# 3  7 blah AFKSD
# 4  8 blah FKSDA
# 5  2 blah  AJSD
```

If you are after something a bit faster, I would go with `stringi::stri_sub` in place of `substring()`.

Comment: guess your answer didn't load. this is the way to go. one of these days I'll learn how to use `with` like a pro.

Comment: interesting, I didn't know the difference between `substr` and `substring`. My initial attempt was with `with` and `substr` which produced a constant vector, before I switched to `sapply`. This is definitely better.

Comment: @MichaelChirico - I had deleted it for a few minutes then realized I had it right.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @Ricky I had to `?substr` to remind myself. I initially thought it was `substr` that accepts vector indices. See the examples in `?substr`

Answer (score 2):

```
aggSN$V3 <- sapply(aggSN$V1, function(x) substr(gen, x-2, x+2))
```

should do the trick.

```
> aggSN
  V1   V2    V3
1  5 blah SDAFK
2  6 blah DAFKS
3  7 blah AFKSD
4  8 blah FKSDA
```

With your different example

```
> aggSN
  V1   V2    V3
1  5 blah SDAFK
2  6 blah DAFKS
3  7 blah AFKSD
4 10 blah SDAFJ
5  2 blah  AJSD
```

Comment: the reproducible example differs from the example where the `V3` is shown. The latter one is what I refer to as "different example".